# Python: Finding a substring within a string from a list, but saving the substring

Tags: python, string, list, substring, any

Basically, I have a list of substrings I am searching a string for. I'm using any() currently and doing some work if one of the words are found in the string. I want to start logging the matches to keep some stats on the matches. I am using any() right now.

Is there a way to do the same thing as any, but store the match in a variable? I'm fetching and searching up to 100 strings every 10 seconds for a list of 25-30 substrings. THe only thing I can think of is iterating through each substring in the list for each string but im not sure of the performance implications with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at this example:

```
s = "Thisisarandomstringthatiwanttotype"
subst = ["This", "random", "hullo", "type"]
```

To return all the substrings that match:

```
filter(lambda x: x in s, subs)
>> ['This', 'random', 'type']
```

To return the starting index of the substrings that match, you can pass the list of strings returned from the code segment above to a map function to find their index:

```
map(lambda x: s.index(x), filter(lambda x: x in s, subs))
>> [0, 7, 30]
```

Similarly, you could check the length of the returned strings using map over the filter:

```
map(lambda x: len(x), filter(lambda x: x in s, subs))
>> [4, 6, 4]
```

Or find the length of the longest substring returned:

```
max(filter(lambda x: x in s, subst), key=len)
>> 'random'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. Regular expressions (As FreddieV4 suggested) are very powerful.

However another simple approach is using a list comprehension like:

```
matches = [x for x in string.split() if x in substrings]
```

Which will loop over the the words in the string and check if the word fits one of the substrings, if so it will be returned and hence can be used for logging purposes.

You can even further extend this to handle a list of strings as input instead of a single string - all in a single list comprehension.

An extensive example is shown below:

```
substrings = ["cool","test","notpresent"]

#get matches for a single string
string = "This is a basic test"
matches = [x for x in string.split() if x in substrings]
print(matches)
# >> ['test']


#get matches for multiple strings
strings = ["I am so awesome", "you are cool", "I think so", "Yep this is a test"]
matches = [x for string in strings for x in string.split() if x in substrings]
print(matches)
# >> ['cool', 'test']
```

Comment: You need to split the string.

Comment: Why is that @JaredGoguen?

Comment: `x for x in string` will iterate over the individual characters in `string`.

Comment: That's really interesting.`x for string in strings for x in string.split() if x in substrings` looks crazy! I'm iterating over the strings for other purposes so  the first example with a single string will probably suit my needs. Thanks!

Comment: Will all matched substrings be stored in 'm' or just the first one?

Comment: All matched substrings. If you don't want duplicates, you can try to use `matches = {x for x in string if x in substrings}`, which will output a dict (hashmap)

Comment: This only works if it is assumed all substrings searched for are words (white-space separated). What about the string `"This is a basic test, or not"`?

Comment: That's true, but that behavior is similar to the `any()` function currently used by OP. If he wants more flexibility, regexes are a better way to go.

Comment: I have searched for a few substrings that have symbols or punctuation. Without previously logging while using any(), I have no idea if they have ever been matched, but it's important I do. Will a substring like this ever be found using the above technique? 'this! is a substring'. If not, maybe I'll use regex to drop all special characters. The punctuation is not important.

Comment: The analysis is happening on word level (this is also the behavior you mentioned in the problem description). `string.split()` will split the string up in words based on the space delimiter. This means that "this is a test, cool.", will become `["this", "is", "a", "test,", "cool."]`. Notice the `test,` and `cool.` Hence the substring here can only represent a word (which can have punctuation in it, but whenever it has a space it will not be found. If you want to be able to match multiple words, with spaces between it, you will need to move to a more advanced technique like regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing, you could use the `re` module.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(r"substring1, substring2, substring3", string)
```

`string` would be the string you're searching through, and `m` would be the variable that contains the group of strings matching whatever substrings you're looking for i.e. `substring1, substring2, substring3`; you could use RegEx patterns rather than substrings as well.

Comment: Would this store all matched substrings in `m` or just the first one?